# How do the lyrics of "上を向いて歩こう" relate to its English title "Sukiyaki"?

Tags: song-lyrics, japanese-language, title

The English title of the Japanese song [上を向いて歩こう](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%B8%8A%E3%82%92%E5%90%91%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6%E6%AD%A9%E3%81%93%E3%81%86) is a head scratcher.

The lyrics:

> 上を向いて歩こう
> 涙がこぼれないように
> 思い出す 春の日
> 一人ぽっちの夜
> 上を向いて歩こう
> にじんだ星をかぞえて
> 思い出す 夏の日
> 一人ぽっちの夜
> 幸せは 雲の上に
> 幸せは 空の上に
> 上を向いて歩こう
> 涙がこぼれないように
> 泣きながら 歩く
> 一人ぽっちの夜
> 思い出す 秋の日
> 一人ぽっちの夜
> 悲しみは星のかげに
> 悲しみは月のかげに
> 上を向いて歩こう
> 涙がこぼれないように
> 泣きながら 歩く
> 一人ぽっちの夜
> 一人ぽっちの夜

[English translation](https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/kyusakamoto/sukiyakiuewomuitearukou.html):

> I look up while I walk
> So the tears won't fall
> Remembering those spring days
> But tonight I'm all alone
> I look up while I walk
> Counting the stars with teary eyes
> Remembering those summer days
> But tonight I'm all alone
> Happiness lies beyond the clouds
> Happiness lies above the sky
> I look up while I walk
> So the tears won't fall
> I cry while I walk
> For I am alone tonight
> Remembering those autumn days
> But tonight I'm all alone
> Sadness hides in the shadow of the stars
> Sadness hides in the shadow of the moon
> I look up while I walk
> So the tears won't fall
> My heart is filled with sorrow
> For tonight I am alone
> For tonight I am alone

What part of the lyrics gave us "sukiyaki"? Who titled the song "sukiyaki"? What does this act of titling mean? And what is its cultural significance?

Comment: Seems to be [answered by Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sukiyaki_(song)#English_title).

Comment: @GarethRees Only the first part of the questions. That Wikipedia section appears to be matter-of-fact about the English title. I'd also like to know _how_ that happened, hence the _who_ question.

Comment: Did you follow the reference?

Comment: @GarethRees Yes and it took me to a Google Books page that I couldn't access.

Comment: If Google Books doesn't work, try [archive.org](https://archive.org/details/billboardbookofn0000bron/page/130/mode/2up).

Comment: @GarethRees Worked like a charm. Now that the _who_ question has been answered, let's see if an answer will come along to talk about the cultural significance of choosing such a title.

Comment: I think [Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%B8%8A%E3%82%92%E5%90%91%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6%E6%AD%A9%E3%81%93%E3%81%86#%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E4%BB%A5%E5%A4%96%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AE%E3%83%92%E3%83%83%E3%83%88) has a bit more story about the reason behind the English name.